# How to setup Windows Media Service using Windows Media Http Streaming Protocol?

Tags: stream, mms, windows-media-player, http-streaming, windows-media-server

Windows Media Service default using MMS protocol. So how to setup Windows Media Service using Windows Media Http Streaming Protocol?

Answer (score 0):

From

```
"start" --> "server manager" --> "media server"
```

and open it, server name is on the left hand.  Select `property`, go to `protocol control`, and enable `HTTP`.